# number of parameters for a Bayesian network over binary random variables

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, multinomial-distribution

I am working through the exercises of a book (Bayesian Reasoning and Machine Learning) for machine learning but I got stuck (I do not understand the question).

The following three variable distributions admit the factorization.

$p(a,b,c) = p(a \vert b) p(b \vert c) p(c)$

All three variables are binary.
The question is how many parameters are required to specify distributions of this form. It might be simple but I am confused by the word "parameter".

In fact we have three different probabilites for success and their complements for non success. And of course we have 9 possible combinations:

$p(a=tr,b=tr,c=tr) = p(a=tr \vert b=tr) p(b=tr \vert c=tr) p(c=tr)\\
p(a=tr,b=tr,c=fa) = p(a=tr \vert b=tr) p(b=tr \vert c=fa) p(c=fa)\\
p(a=tr,b=fa,c=tr) = p(a=tr \vert b=fa) p(b=fa \vert c=tr) p(c=tr)\\
p(a=tr,b=fa,c=fa) = p(a=tr \vert b=fa) p(b=fa \vert c=fa) p(c=fa)\\
p(a=fa,b=tr,c=tr) = p(a=fa \vert b=tr) p(b=tr \vert c=tr) p(c=tr)\\
p(a=fa,b=tr,c=fa) = p(a=fa \vert b=tr) p(b=tr \vert c=fa) p(c=fa)\\
p(a=fa,b=fa,c=tr) = p(a=fa \vert b=fa) p(b=fa \vert c=tr) p(c=tr)\\
p(a=fa,b=fa,c=fa) = p(a=fa \vert b=fa) p(b=fa \vert c=fa) p(c=fa)$

Can someone give me a hint so that I am able to understand what is meant with "parameters"? Thank you!

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be a random variable denoting the result of a coin flip where $x = 1$ signifies heads and $x = 0$ signifies tails. $x$ will follow the [Bernoulli distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution), which has one parameter, $p$, denoting the probability of $x=1$ (i.e. probability of landing heads).

Now let's imagine there are two types of coins ($c=1$ or $c=0$) which may have different probabilities of landing heads. Let $b$ be a random variable denoting the result of a coin flip. How many parameters would it take to characterize the distribution of $b$ conditional on the type of coin $c$?

Comment: Hello Matthew. It would require two "parameters" - one for "choosing" the coin and one defining the probability ($p(b|c)$). The answer of the question is then, that we need 2 + 2 + 1 parameters for the full specification of the distribution

Comment: @bobby $p(b = 1 | c= 0) = \alpha$ requires one parameter $\alpha$ and $p(b = 1 | c = 1) = \beta $ requires one parameter, hence it requires two parameters $(\alpha, \beta)$ to describe the distribution of  $p(b|c)$ It would be $2+2+1=5$.

Comment: @MatthewGunn Could you clarify this a little more? I have the same exact answer as bobby and I do not understand your answer. First, $p(b = 1 | c= 0) $ requires $1$ parameter, $p(b = 1 | c= 1) $ requires another one, so you need two parameters. Then where do the five parameters come from?

Comment: @D1X And then for this particular question, you have another parameter for $P(a = 1 | b = 1)$ and another for $P(a=1 | b=0)$ and another for $P(c=1)$.